# How to disable "share" feature in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Whenever I have text in an EditText, the user can do a longpress over the text and the "Copy/Cut/Share" options hover over it.

It is OK for me to let Copy/Cut (Paste also) options appear (although not really needed), but I really can't let those text trigger the "share" option appear.

Is this feasible without reinventing the wheel ?

The XML code to define the EditText is quite basic, currently testing against API 30:

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/settings_doctor_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/dr_name"
                    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />
```

Having had a review on EditText and TextView documentation, but I still haven't found any idea on do to deal with this.

Did I miss anything in the docs ? Thanks for reading !

Comment: "but I really can't let those text trigger the "share" option appear" -- why? After all, the user can still share the text, by means of the clipboard. All you will do is annoy the user, with no change in what the user can accomplish. Bear in mind that other apps (e.g., Google Translate) can add additional options to that menu via `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT`, and that device manufacturers can tinker with the menu as well.

Comment: Because my App is designed in a Kiosk type Android machine were I don't want to let system "share" features launch from this App. No problem letting copy & paste, just not let the App launch other Apps in any way. To sum up, as per my customer request: "remove share option" ;-). Can I override ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT in a useful way ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at _TextView's_ [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(android.view.ActionMode.Callback))

Comment: If your app will only be used on specific hardware, there is a chance that `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()` will be sufficient, as Cheticamp suggests. Whoever is setting up the hardware will need to ensure that they do not add any apps that might cause extra options to appear in that menu, and you will need to do adequate testing to ensure the manufacturer did not mess with how that menu works. If your app is going to be used on *arbitrary* hardware... then I doubt that you will find a guaranteed solution, though `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()` is a good starting point.

Comment: @CommonsWare All good points. So, it's still the wild west out there. Am I wrong in thinking that returning false from `onCreateActionMode()` would do it _most_ of the time and would avoid any additional options that may be added by others? In any case, this would be something to document as a potential failing and to add to the test bed.

Comment: @Cheticamp: "Am I wrong in thinking that returning false from onCreateActionMode() would do it most of the time and would avoid any additional options that may be added by others?" -- AFAIK, `false` is supposed to suppress the entire menu, which is not what the OP asked for. It might be the right *answer* for the OP, insofar as copy/paste might not be relevant for their app, so removing the menu completely might be a reasonable solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the OP would be OK with complete suppression. _"It is OK for me to let Copy/Cut (Paste also) options appear (although not really needed)..."_ Anyway, the OP has an answer.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Ah, good point, I overlooked the parenthetical expression there. Sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare No worries. Regards.

Comment: @Cheticamp thanks for pointing that documentation link ! I'm going to give it a try with the idea to take out the ```R.id.shareText``` default action. My hardware is controlled enough that it has a good chance to be the best solution. I'm gonna google about those functions to have a better understanding of how to achieve this.

Comment: @CommonsWare I agree with you that the HW might let me try to eliminate the actions. If everything fails I can always return false and eliminate all actions as you discussed with Cheticamp , thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 3):

I share with you the solution derived from your comments that has been implemented and tested:

I created a my own TextEdit:

```
public class EditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    public EditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(removeShareActionMode);
    }

    ActionMode.Callback removeShareActionMode = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        @TargetApi(26)
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            if (menu != null) {
                menu.removeItem(android.R.id.shareText);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    }
}
```

And used it everywhere. Works as expected. Thanks to all for contributing. I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote your answers.

Comment: The `onCreateActionMode` check did the trick! Nice one

Comment: This worked great, thank you! I also needed another constructor `public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` for the element to work correctly in my app.